# Laravel React Force browser download file from ajax request?

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs, laravel-5, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel with React js . i want to download files so i use `return response()->download($pathToFile)` where pathToFile is located in public dir.my url is guarded by auth middleware.
i tried solution at [Force Download via Ajax and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774282/force-download-via-ajax-and-php) but doesn't work.

In another hand i use axios to send ajax request to get file, I get response headers like that[image: response header]

and get encoded response like [image]

How i force browser to download file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force Download via Ajax and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774282/force-download-via-ajax-and-php)

Comment: You cannot "force" a browser to download anything. It must be accepted by the end user.

Answer (score 2):

I was using axios so i added responseType: 'blob' to request header then used filesave or responseType: 'blob' or react-file-download to download file

```
axios.get(url, {responseType: 'blob'})
    .then((res) => {
        FileDownload(res.data, filename);
    });
```