# Browser not downloading file from PHP script

Tags: php

Background:
I have a table on the website that users can select rows from and then click an export button to download a .csv of those rows.

I'm creating an array of arrays from the table on the front-end and passing the array via AJAX to a PHP script that is using fputcsv() to put them in .csv format. I'm able to echo the result, as well as push the results to a .csv file on the server, and both display correctly. But for whatever reason I can't get the browser to offer the file for download.

I've referenced quite a few stackoverflow articles as well as done research into HTTP headers and nothing seems to do the trick.

My code is pasted below:

```
<?php 

// this is the array of arrays passed via AJAX
$gaps = $_POST["gaps"];

function array_to_csv_download($array, $filename='export.csv', $delimiter=",") {
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'";');

    // open the "output" stream
    // see http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#refsect2-wrappers.php-unknown-unknown-unknown-descriptioq
    $f = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    foreach ($array as $line) {
        fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter);
    }
}  

array_to_csv_download($gaps, 'gaps.csv');
```

Comment: Change your header from "Content-type: text/csv" to "Content-type: binary/octet-stream"

Comment: Your code works fine for me, without the $gaps variable, so check there if you are missing something

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can not download files with AJAX. Your code looks ok, the problem is on the frontend.

Because you have post values, you need a `<form>` to send those values. So, remove the ajax request and use a `<form target="_blank" action=".....">`. The `target="_blank"` is needed so the form opens a new window. You can have the form already generated in your code or you can generate it using `document.createElement("form")` and build it from the javascript code.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774282/force-download-via-ajax-and-php) answer for AJAX unable to download and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896724/how-to-open-a-new-window-on-form-submit) one for opening a new window from a form.

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964927/how-to-create-a-form-dynamically-via-javascript) you can find more details about how to generate a form using javascript.

Comment: This is essentially the answer. You cannot download files using AJAX. I ended up returning the filepath and then redirecting the window to that location in order to download.